# Transactional Emails Logo showing wrong URL https:/=/ but i want URL https://

Tags: magento2, order-email

Current URL
`<img src=3D"https:/=/magento225.com/pub/media/email/logo/stores/1/logo_email.png" alt=3D"></a>`

But I want
`<img src=3D"https://magento225.com/pub/media/email/logo/stores/1/logo_email.png" alt=3D"></a>`

Mean I want URL https:// instead of https:/=/ in Transactional Emails when customer received order email.

Comment: By default it must work the way you want it. There seems to be 2 possibility for the issue. 1. You did configure URL in correct on Store configuration. Less probability of this option as this will not allow you to browse the website. 2. You may have override the header email template which possibly consist of a type in URL.